# Linkedin Api multipart upload url throws 500

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm using the following code to try and upload a video via the LinkedIn ["Videos API beta"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api-beta?tabs=http)...

```
//Get video file path
$filePath = Storage::disk('public')->path(
    Storage::urlToPath($post->meta['attachments']['videos'][0])
);

//Open file
$fileHandler = fopen($filePath, "r");
            
//Register linkedin upload
$upload = $client->post('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videos?action=initializeUpload', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer {token}'
    ],
    'body' => json_encode([
        'initializeUploadRequest' => [
            'owner' => 'urn:li:person:' . $social['data']['user_id'],
            'purpose' => 'FEED_VIDEO',
            'fileSizeBytes' => filesize($filePath),
            'uploadCaptions' => false,
            'uploadThumbnail' => false
        ]
    ], true)
]);

//Parse request
$upload = json_decode($upload->getBody()->getContents(), true);

//Upload video
$uploadPartIds = [];
foreach($upload['value']['uploadInstructions'] as $instruction) {
    //Upload part (500 error with this request)
    $chunkedUpload = $client->put($instruction['uploadUrl'], [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        ],
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'     => 'upload',
                'contents' => fread($fileHandler, $instruction['lastByte'] - $instruction['firstByte']),
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    //Push etag
    $uploadPartIds[] = $chunkedUpload->getHeader('ETag')[0];
}
```

However when it tries to upload a chunk to the first uploadUrl from linkedin I receive a 500 error saying "Your LinkedIn Network Will Be Back Soon, We’ve notified our operations staff that you are having a problem reaching LinkedIn.  We’ll get you reconnected soon."

Comment: A 500 error means the server crashed. LinkedIn would need to tell you why their server is crashing, not us

Comment: Yes thanks @ADyson I am aware of that, however LinkedIn have asked for issues to be placed on here https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a526157